# How to edit or add tag colors

Tags: macos, preview, finder-tag

In Preview.app for macOS 10.13.3, how do I remove a tag from the drop-down menu and add additional colour tag, other than the few shown? I made a tag which I want to remove from the drop-down menu. Also, I wonder if it is possible to add custom colors to tags?

Comment: Did you try anything in System Preferences > Finder > Tags? If so, what? If not, try there.

Answer (score 4):

The tags shown when saving or modifying a file are **Finder tags**, not specific to Preview, etc. Therefore you are limited to the colours available for Finder tags.

Go to Finder → Preferences, then choose the Tags tab.

[image]
[image]

Click on a tag, then choose – to remove it.

Tag colours can be changed by right-clicking on a tag in the list and choosing a new colour for it.

[image]

> Drag your favourite tags to the area below to make them available for quick use in Finder menus.

Comment: To complete grg's answer: As of macOS Mojave, it is not possible to add custom colours. The only colours available are the 8 colours provided by macOS.

Comment: @PRouleau Looking at the screenshots above it looks as if this already was the case before Mojave.

Comment: I've clarified the answer, custom colours have never been available for Finder tags hence they are not available in Preview.